# Simple UV unwrap with unexpected results - 2.78

Tags: uv

Pretty simple UV unwrap, not anything I'd consider complex but for the life of me I cannot understand the results. I have prepared a file with just the object in the state of unwrap - hopefully someone can figure out what I could have done? Not sure this is related to 2.78 but that is what I am using.

All doubles have been removed - just by the way, and scale was applied.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your vertices of the *Uv Island* ***pinned***. Select the island with <kbd>A</kbd> in *Uv Editor* and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or go to Uvs-->Unpin to ***unpin it***. Then unwrap it (<kbd>U</kbd>-->Unwrap) and it's gona look fine.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Paul - not sure how or why I pinned all my verts, but glad you helped!

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, this happens from time to time, mostly if you have "unusual" (from Blender's point of view) topology like the area where the trouser legs are turned up.

Just delete your UV map in *Properties - Data - UV Maps*, then try UV unwrap again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Duarte - that's a helpful tip for next time I mess up!